# Zend Rest Route: goto the right method (get/put/post/delete)

Tags: zend-framework, zend-controller-router

I am retiring a custom PHP project that was used as an API.

I need to support such URLS such as

/post/{id}/copy.json (copy post with {id}
/post (all posts)
/post/{id} (return one post)

So far its going okay, however routing I'm finding difficult. I would like Zend to detect what type of request it is and then use the correct method. I am leaning towards putting that in My_Controller_Rest predispatch, passing a variable back to the controller and then in indexAction doing $this->getAction()

Thoughts? I kind of assumed using Zend_Rest_Controller it would fire off the right method, and unless I'm doing it wrong, its not.

All my controllers extend an abstract class,

Controller:

```
<?php

class Post_IndexController extends My_Controller_Rest
{


    public function init()
    {
    }


    public function indexAction()
    {

    }


    public function getAction()
    {
    }


    public function postAction()
    {
    }


    public function putAction()
    {
    }


    public function deleteAction()
    {
    }


}
```

My Controller Rest

```
<?php


abstract class My_Controller_Rest extends Zend_Rest_Controller {


    public function preDispatch() {

        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
        $request        = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest();
        $this->output   = null;

        //get registry versions
        $config         = Zend_Registry::get('config');
        $cache          = Zend_Registry::get('cache');
        $log            = Zend_Registry::get('log');
        $loggers        = Zend_Registry::get('loggers');

        //internal to the view
        $this->_config      = $config;
        $this->_cache       = $cache;
        $this->_log         = $log;

        $this->data = array();
        $this->data['module']   = $request->getModuleName();
        $this->data['controller'] = $request->getControllerName();
        $this->data['action']   = $request->getActionName();
        $this->data['loggers']  = $loggers;
    }


    public function postDispatch() {
        header('Content-type: text/json');
        header('Content-type: application/json');

        echo json_encode(array('output' => $this->output, 'data' => $this->data));
        exit;
    }


}
```

UPDATE:

I resolved this by using the Resauce: https://github.com/mikekelly/Resauce

You can find my improvements by looking here: https://github.com/mikekelly/Resauce/issues/1